# Ubuntu 22.04 does not invoke Quodlibet

Tags: 22.04, quodlibet

Ubuntu 21.10 could invoke Quodlibet. Ubuntu 22.04 cannot.

If anybody knows how to invoke (ie start) Quodlibet on Ubuntu 22.04, please provide instructions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I, too, hit this issue with quodlibet version 4.4.0-2 after updating to Ubuntu 22.04, and prepared a patch that has since been released into the jammy-updates repository as version 4.4.0-2ubuntu0.1. If you have it enabled, the updated package should soon be made available in your mirror of the Ubuntu archive.

You can see the Launchpad bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quodlibet/+bug/1964791

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Maia.  Many thanks for the link.  Somehow I missed this in my searches.  As suspected, the issue is a new release.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct ppa enables the install for the newest release:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lazka/ppa

sudo update

sudo apt install quodlibet